# Angular to compile only dom elements within the ng-controller

Tags: angularjs

I have huge application with like 100 controllers. Assume it is a twitter app. And people started using {{ }} in their tweets.

Lets say a tweet contains "{{ imp : hello }}" is loaded into the dom from the database on page load which is not inside the controller. But when angular loads ng-app which is set for whole page will throw an $parse error. Is there way in which i can tell angular to compile only the dom present within the ng-controller.

To be clear i want angular to leave {{ imp : hello }} as it is.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div ng-app='sampleApp'>
      <p> {{ imp : hello }} {{ hello }} </p>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller='mycontroller'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide some code: plunkr or jsfiddle

Comment: What about changing the interpolation symbols? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider#startSymbol

Comment: @apairet: I thought about it, but it has the same problems: if the OP chooses [[ instead of {{ and the data contains [[, you have the same problem.

Comment: yeah right any other solutions?

Comment: I do agree. Sorry, have no other solution in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to modify a server-side template, I'm too prefer the @JBNizet solution i.e. adding the `ng-non-bindable` in your server-side template that used to generate those `p` tags.

But if you really need to do it client-side, you could write a directive to intercept a normal compilation, then manually compile only elements that contain a `ng-controller` attribute.

```
app.directive('compileOnlyNgController', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    terminal: true, // intercept a normal compilation
    priority: 1000,
    link: function (scope, element) {
      // compile only children elements that contain a ng-controller attribute;
      $compile(element[0].querySelectorAll('[ng-controller]'))(scope);
    }
  }
});
```

And place it in to your `ng-app` element:

```
<div ng-app="sampleApp" compile-only-ng-controller>
  <p>{{ imp : hello }} {{ hello }}</p>
  <div ng-controller="mycontroller">
    <p>{{ hello }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/zo4LyAt3d1WMhkayIbqb?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would prefer @JBNizet solution if my application is little.

Answer (score 1):

```
<span ng-non-bindable>{{ imp : hello }}</span>
```

Documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable

Comment: Yes i used that. Lets say my application is huge. I have 100 controllers. In between i have texts like this. Then i need to go to each place and add this. Is there a way in which i can do it in one go?

Comment: What's the use case exactly? Text coming from the database is not compiled. Why do you need so many double moustaches in your pages? Are you writing documentation for angular?

Comment: Lets say my application is like twitter. Now users adding tweets using {{ hello : here }} in which case i have to display text exactly as it is which are neither inside the controller nor the directives.

Comment: This won't be compiled by angular. It's a dynamic value, not static text in your view.

Comment: Boss it is not loaded via ajax request atleast the initial view. It is loaded into dom on page load.

Comment: So you're in fact dynamically generating an angular view at server-side? That's a strange idea. Anyway, ng-non-bindable is the only solution I see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59849/discussion-between-vasu-akeel-and-jb-nizet).